# Dimming UIImageView in Custom UITableViewCell when selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I implemented a custom UITableView cell.

All was good, until I clicked on my tableview cell.

Usually a tableview cell dims when I tap on it.

This is because cell.selectionStyle is set to .default, and the UITableViewCell's subclass dims itself with the call to setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool).

**My problem is that, when selecting a row(cell) in my table, everything but UIImageView that is included in the UITableViewCell contentview gets correctly dimmed.**

I've tried including a black UIView overlay on top of my UIImgeView, and overriding setHighlighted of my custom tableview cell to vary the UIView's opacity to match the rest of the cell contents. However, not only does this affect fail to reliably trigger every time, but it also does not carry the same animation with the rest of the cell components. The opacity change of the overlay is instant, while the default dimming affect provided by iOS is gradual.

I really would appreciate any insight. I imagine this is a question many others probably had, but googling did not yield any results. Thank you. Just in case, I am including the code for my custom UITableViewCell below.

```
import UIKit

class HouseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var houseThumbnail: UIImageView!
var houseName: UILabel!
var houseRating: UILabel!
var houseReviewCount: UILabel!
var houseRent: UILabel!
var imageDim: UIView!


override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
    super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    houseThumbnail = UIImageView()
    self.contentView.addSubview(houseThumbnail)

    houseName = UILabel()
    self.contentView.addSubview(houseName)

    houseRating = UILabel()
    self.contentView.addSubview(houseRating)

    houseReviewCount = UILabel()
    self.contentView.addSubview(houseReviewCount)

    houseRent = UILabel()
    self.contentView.addSubview(houseRent)

    imageDim = UIView()
    imageDim.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
    self.contentView.addSubview(imageDim)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


func makeConstraints() {

    houseThumbnail?.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.width.equalToSuperview().dividedBy(2)
        make.height.equalToSuperview()
        make.left.equalToSuperview()
    }

    houseName?.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.width.equalToSuperview().dividedBy(2)
        make.height.equalTo(30)
        make.right.equalToSuperview()
        make.top.equalToSuperview()
    }

    houseRating.snp.makeConstraints{ (make) -> Void in
        make.height.equalTo(30)
        make.top.equalTo(houseName.snp.bottom)
        make.left.equalTo(self.snp.centerX)
    }

    houseReviewCount.snp.makeConstraints{ (make) -> Void in
        make.height.equalTo(30)
        make.top.equalTo(houseName.snp.bottom)
        make.right.equalToSuperview()
    }

    houseRent.snp.makeConstraints{ (make) -> Void in
        make.width.equalToSuperview().dividedBy(2)
        make.height.equalTo(30)
        make.right.equalToSuperview()
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }

    imageDim.snp.makeConstraints{ (make) -> Void in
        make.width.height.top.left.equalTo(houseThumbnail)
    }
}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}


override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
     super.setSelected(highlighted, animated: animated)

    /* Logic to dim imageview */
    if highlighted {
        imageDim.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
    } else {
        imageDim.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in

```
override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
     super.setSelected(highlighted, animated: animated)

    /* Logic to dim imageview */
    if highlighted {
        imageDim.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
    } else {
        imageDim.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
    }
}
```

As far as I know, UITableViewCell's `setHighlighted` isn't called when you select the cell.
Instead, change it to

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
     super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    /* Logic to dim imageview */
    if selected {
        imageDim.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
    } else {
        imageDim.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
    }
}
```